# How do I create test dataset for tf ranking model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, gam, ranking-functions

I'm trying to evaluate the NeuralGAMS LTR model using a test set and I'm doing this to create it:

```
# Build Test Dataset for Model Ingestion
features = preprocess_features(features_file)
feature_cols = np.array(features['cols'])

# Create specs for pipeline
context_spec_ = {}
example_spec_ = {feat: tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, default_value=0.0) for feat in feature_cols}
label_spec_ = ('relevance_label', tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int64, default_value=-1))

dataset_hparams = tfr.keras.pipeline.DatasetHparams(
    train_input_pattern='tfrecord_HJ/HJ/all_data/train.tfrecords',
    valid_input_pattern='tfrecord_GD/Golden_Data/LibSVM_format/test.tfrecords',
    train_batch_size=128,
    valid_batch_size=1,
    dataset_reader=tfr.keras.pipeline.DatasetHparams.dataset_reader)

# Define Dataset Builder
dataset_builder = tfr.keras.pipeline.SimpleDatasetBuilder(
    {},
    example_spec_,
    mask_feature_name="example_list_mask",
    label_spec=label_spec_,
    hparams=dataset_hparams,
    sample_weight_spec=None)

ds = dataset_builder.build_valid_dataset()
```

When I use this ds for predictions this way:
`predictions = model.predict(ds)`

I get "When providing an infinite dataset, you must specify the number of steps to run (if you did not intend to create an infinite dataset, make sure to not call `repeat()` on the dataset)." error.

My questions are:

1. Why is an infinite dataset created when I'm just reading from an existing tfrecord to create it.
2. When I add 'steps', how do I get the predictions for all the data
3. How do I map these back to the inputs?
4. Better way to get predictions?